# I've wrongly removed /etc/apache2

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm wondering whether it's possible to install apache2 from scratch, I tried to install it and  many times I was informed that a configuration file was removed, and everytime I chose to install the package responsible version. When starting apache service I have this `apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName` and the localhost url shows `Page Web inaccessible`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove it all & install xampp (lampp for linux)

Comment: Actually I'd like to keep my dev environment as before if possible, by using packages separately.

Comment: that works if you are a network administrator & understand each package which you don't seem to do... a dev environment is ide+ whatever libs+debug tools you use to develop, not your local server that you use to test, not to developp;conclusion the way you create a local apache/mysql server on your machine has nothing to do with your dev environment; g luck

Answer (score 1):

Just add to apache2.conf

```
Servername localhost
```

into last line.

(PATH)
    sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf